# Jquery Ajax Chat (works once) - PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am new to ajax. I just started learning it by implementing with CodeIgniter.

I am building a "chat room" in my website, I can already save the message into the database and display it in the box using ajax. But my problem here is that it only works the first time. If I type again another message it won't work. Here is what I have done so far. Please advise.

jquery/ajax code:

```
$("#sendchat").click(function () {
    if ($("#inputchat").val().length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo config_item('base_url').'data/savechat/'?>" + $("#inputchat").val(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("body").html(result);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

view:

```
<div id="chatbox">
    <?php foreach($chats as $ch):?>
        <?php
            echo $ch['message_content'];
        ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>

    <input id="inputchat" type="text" />
    <button id="sendchat">SEND</button>
```

controller:

```
public function chat(){            
    $data['report'] = "none";  
    $data['chats'] = $this->dbhelper->getchats();
    $this->template->write_view("content","chatwithadmin",$data); 
    $this->template->write_view("header", "header_menu",$data);
    $this->template->render();
}
public function savechat($message){            
    $data['report'] = "none";
    $this->dbhelper->savechat($message);
    $this->chat();    
}
```

model:

```
public function savechat($message){        
        $this->db->insert("tbl_messages",array("message_content"=>$message,"user_id"=>1,"date_sent"=>date("m-d-y")));
}
public function getchats(){
    $query = $this->db->get("tbl_messages");            
    eturn $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: your ajax seems good to me.. Have you check your console log, if there are errors or is it making another ajax call? if none then lets presume that your `if` statement is not working but supposedly it should be working

Comment: I've got my error's answer (I should have use  delegated event handler). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that when you do

```
 $("body").html(result);
```

you are removing the current bind on

```
$("#sendchat").click(function(){...});
```

So the second time you press it, it's not linked to your click event.

I would suggest to only write the respond in the chatbox instead of rewriting the whole view.

OR

You could try this :

```
$(this).delegate('#sendchat', 'click', function() {...});
```

Hope it helped you !

Answer (score 1):

As [@Gabtheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2170794/gabtheviking) said,

```
$("body").html(result);
```

destroys the attached event handlers. To solve this,

1. you need to replace the relevant content without destroying the handler. or
2. you need to rebind the events after loading the content. or
3. use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

I'd prefer to use event delegation, for eg. in your case attach the event handler to the `document`

```
$(document).on('click', '#sendchat', function (e) {
    if ($("#inputchat").val().length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo config_item('base_url').'data/savechat/'?>" + $("#inputchat").val(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("body").html(result);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

uses [`jQuery.on();`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @Kentot glad this helped, and marking as answer is much appreciated :)